# Gradle jar not running. Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, gradle

I have created a very basic gradle java project that prints "Hello Word". The main class builds and runs fine. When i try to run `java -jar out\artifacts\helloWorld_jar\helloWorld.jar` on the command line it gives me this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.exmple.helloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.exmple.helloWorld
```

here is how my directory looks

```
|-gradle
|-.idea
|-build
|-gradle
|-META-INF
|-out
 | -artifacts
 | -helloWorld_jar
 | -helloWorld.jar
|-src
 |-main
  |-java
   |- com.exmple
    |-helloWorld
 |-test
|build.gradle
etc...
```

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
jar{
    manifest{
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.exmple.helloWorld"
    }

}
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have tried both single quotes and double quotes and it still runs an error. Any ideas on how to fix this? I have been trying for a few days now.

PS. example is spelt wrong, but its spelt exmple throughout

Comment: exmple -> example

Comment: I think your missing the application plugin , https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the full classname is `com.exmpl.helloWorld`, then the source directory structure should be:

```
|-src
 |-main
  |-java
   |-com
    |-exmpl
     |-helloWorld.java
```

not

```
|-src
 |-main
  |-java
   |-com.exmple
    |-helloWorld
```

Please read [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928) for more information.  (It explains in depth the **many** things that can cause this problem.)

Answer (score 0):

It is looking like you have a typo in the path that you are passing:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.**exmple**.helloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.**exmple**.helloWorld"

An **A** is missing from *example* package

Comment: it is spelt exmple for everything. I know it is spelt wrong (oops). I have checked the package and the path and everything is exmple